# Representing 3 Dimensional and stacked Graph with Textual data with pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Currently I'm handling the dataset which has data in below format:

```
                                              Tweets Classified  FreqWord
0   calm director day science meetings nasal talk...   Positive   drought
1                               love thought drought   Positive   drought
2   reign mother kerr funny none tried make come ...   Positive   drought
3   wonder could help thai market b post reuters ...   Negative   drought
4   wonder could help thai market b post reuters ...   Negative     crops
5   wonder could help thai market b post reuters ...   Negative     crops
6   wonder could help thai market b post reuters ...   Negative  business
7   every child safe drinking water thank uk aid ...   Positive   drought
8   every child safe drinking water thank uk aid ...   Positive     water
9   times live wow watch drought drought asks cap...   Positive   drought
```

Info of this dataframe is:

```
f2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 483 entries, 0 to 482
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Tweets        483 non-null object
Classified    483 non-null object
FreqWord      483 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 11.4+ KB
```

I'm trying to plot a 3D and stacked graph for which I tried a naive method by having count, and then passing to plot 3D graph.

```
PS = (f2['Classified']=='Positive').sum()
H_PS = (f2['Classified']=='Highly Positive').sum()
M_PS = (f2['Classified']=='Moderately Positive').sum()
NG = (f2['Classified']=='Negative').sum()
H_NG = (f2['Classified']=='Highly Negative').sum()
M_NG = (f2['Classified']=='Moderately Negative').sum()
text = "Fuzzy Logic Stats"
pltr.stackplotter(H_NG, M_NG, NG, H_PS, M_PS, PS, text)
```

To which I recieved, something very inaccurate:
[image: 3D Plotting for Data]

Here's the code, that plotted this:

```
def stackplotter3d(HighlyNEG, ModeratelyNEG, NEG, HighlyPOS, ModeratelyPOS, POS, text):    
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
        H_NG, M_NG, NG, H_PS, M_PS, PS = HighlyNEG, ModeratelyNEG, NEG, HighlyPOS, ModeratelyPOS, POS
        Polarities = [H_NG, M_NG, NG, H_PS, M_PS, PS]
        ax.set_xlabel('Polarities')
        ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
        ax.set_zlabel('z')

        ax.set_xlim3d(0, 14)
        ax.set_ylim3d(0, 4)

        xpos = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
        ypos = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        zpos = Polarities

        dx = np.ones(6)
        dy = np.ones(6)
        dz = [np.random.random(6) for i in range(4)]# the heights of the 4 bar sets

        _zpos = zpos  # the starting zpos for each bar

        for i in range(len(dz)):
            ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, _zpos, dx, dy, dz[i], color='red')
            _zpos += dz[i]  # add the height of each bar to know where to start the next
        plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
        plt.show()
```

**I'd like to hear if you can, help represent this graph in more accurate and complete way.**

Comment: How can we know that this is inaccurate? Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you can check the Graph screenshot, that should've been stacked, however it returns values suspended in mid air. That I guess suffices inaccurate. However I'll go through, the link.